# Pandas `try df.loc[x]` vs `x in df.index`

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with one column. I would like to write a function that returns the column value for a given key value; or a different (constant) value if the key is not in the index. I can think of (at least) two reasonable ways to implement this -- **aside from speed is there a reason one would be better than the other?**

And w/r/t speed, with len(df) = 10k and len(ids_to_check) = 20k, the try/except is about 2x slower. This is surprising to me since the other method has to traverse the index twice. **Any intuitive explanation for this behavior?**

1. Using a `try`/`except` block

   ```
   def attempt_1(id_val,df):
       try:
           return df.loc[id_val]
       except KeyError:
           return constant_val

   %timeit [attempt_1(i,df) for i in ids_to_check]

   1 loops, best of 3: 480 ms per loop
   ```
2. Using `in` to test if `id_val` is in the index

   ```
   def attempt_2(id_val,df):
       if id_val in df.index:
           return df.loc[id_val]
       else:
           return constant_val

   %timeit [attempt_2(i,df) for i in ids_to_check]

   1 loops, best of 3: 235 ms per loop
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Create a test frame

```
In [22]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = np.random.randn(10000)))
```

Select some ids

```
In [21]: ids_to_check = np.random.choice(np.arange(0,20000),size=10000,replace=False)
```

Your methods

```
In [18]: %timeit [attempt_2(i,df) for i in ids_to_check]
1 loops, best of 3: 409 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit [attempt_1(i,df) for i in ids_to_check]
1 loops, best of 3: 620 ms per loop
```

An efficient method, using vectorized lookups. `isin` returns a boolean array if the location values are in the index; indexing off of this is pretty fast.

Then I reindex to recover the original index and fill with the value for the missing entries

```
In [19]: %timeit df.A.loc[df.index.isin(ids_to_check)].reindex(df.index).fillna(-100)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.74 ms per loop
```

This returns a Series; easily could have returned the DataFrame

```
In [20]: df.A.loc[df.index.isin(np.random.choice(np.arange(0,20000),size=10000,replace=False))].reindex(df.index).fillna(-100)
Out[20]: 
0    -100.000000
1      -0.485421
2      -0.397338
3    -100.000000
4       0.573031
5    -100.000000
6       0.359699
7       0.298462
8    -100.000000
9      -1.274819
10   -100.000000
11      0.112869
12   -100.000000
13     -2.251186
14     -0.846211
...
9985   -100.000000
9986     -0.988055
9987     -0.080460
9988   -100.000000
9989      1.007490
9990     -1.454466
9991      0.875455
9992   -100.000000
9993   -100.000000
9994      0.194506
9995   -100.000000
9996   -100.000000
9997   -100.000000
9998     -0.477828
9999     -0.777487
Name: A, Length: 10000, dtype: float64
```

So the answer is always use vectorized methods, never loop.